# jQuery to check viewport size and fire function

Tags: jquery, css, html, media-queries

I'm Creating a website using a mobile first approach. When the website is viewed on a mobile, the content is stacked

When the screen expands to Ipad size , I want to add some extra images to a gallery (progressive enhancement). I have two options

1) Use media queries + display:none to hide content on the Mobile and then Show content  in ipad mode. However, **I believe this is bad for performance as we are downloading the assets unnecessarily and hiding them**

2) Use JQUERY to insert content when screen size reaches 500px - 600px

Below is the append code.. My quest is : How can I create a function / IF statement to check view port size and only fire when screen is between 500 - 600 px
The extra images will be show at 500 - 600px , then removed at any other width

```
$("#theDiv").append("<img id='Img' src='ThisismyImg.png'/>");
```

Many thanks,
P

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if ($(window).outerWidth() > 500 && $(window).outerWidth() < 600) {
    $("#theDiv").append("<img id='Img' src='ThisismyImg.png'/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this is bad for performance as we are downloading the assets
>   unnecessarily and hiding them

Actually, you can have media queries load images 'on-demand', [there is a great article here on it](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/).

There are three main approaches:

1. Nest the image within a parent element with `display:none` set, until media query is met
2. Add an additional media query with `min-width` where the image is unset
3. As above, but using `min-device-pixel-ratio`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helpful to you

```
 if ($(window).Width() > 500 && $(window).Width() < 600) {
     $("#theDiv").append("<img id='Img' src='ThisismyImg.png'/>");
 }
```